# (ARCH) Linux / Windows Dual Boot (separate hard drives): Windows SSD now invalid boot medium

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, ssd, arch-linux

So I installed Windows 10 (in EFI i think) on `/dev/sdb` a few weeks ago and had a test installation of Arch linux installed in `/dev/sda`

At this point i was able to boot into either OS, but today i wanted to fix a clean setup of Arch and now the Arch SSD is the only one recognised to have a valid OS on it. I have tried disabling Arch SSD in the BIOS settings to be able to select the Windows SDD, but it just boots into that `the selected drive is not a valid boot medium...` message. Now this time I installed Arch EFI with [grub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS0H3vQUtRw) instead of [systemd-boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dva-7SCYTqY) (mainly cause the systemd-boot installation would always fail if i added disk encryption), but why would an installation of 1 OS on an entirely different hard drive break another?

Any idea why my Windows 10 is not recognised as valid anymore?

Comment: If the OSes are installed in UEFI mode then you don't select drives but EFI boot entries. Regardless of where the OSes are installed, the firmware will always read the ESP (EFI system partition) looking for bootloders. So... 1. Do NOT change the drive order/priority and if you did already make sure to select now the one containing the ESP and 2. You should be able to boot Windows independently just by selecting its EFI entry and (...)

Comment: 3. Typically, for a multi-boot, we boot the Grub (or similar) entry and that should also have the option to chainload back to Windows or other OSes listed should the user want to boot anything else. This is about Ubuntu but applicable to any modern Linux distro: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi